# What does the '@' operator do in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm looking at some Scala code in the Akka codebase, and this code snippet below is responsible for handling an Exception.

```
override val supervisorStrategy =
OneForOneStrategy(loggingEnabled = false) {
  case e @ InvalidAssociation(localAddress, remoteAddress, reason) ⇒
    log.warning("Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [{}]. " +
      "Address is now gated for {} ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: {}",
      remoteAddress, settings.RetryGateClosedFor.toMillis, reason.getMessage)
    endpoints.markAsFailed(sender(), Deadline.now + settings.RetryGateClosedFor)
    AddressTerminatedTopic(context.system).publish(AddressTerminated(remoteAddress))
    Stop

  case ShutDownAssociation(localAddress, remoteAddress, _) ⇒
    log.debug("Remote system with address [{}] has shut down. " +
      "Address is now gated for {} ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters.",
      remoteAddress, settings.RetryGateClosedFor.toMillis)
    endpoints.markAsFailed(sender(), Deadline.now + settings.RetryGateClosedFor)
    AddressTerminatedTopic(context.system).publish(AddressTerminated(remoteAddress))
    Stop
```

The code on line 3, `case e @ InvalidAssociation` - InvalidAssociation is indeed an exception type, but why is the `e @` necessary and what does it do?

Comment: @DonRoby didn't show up in any search results when I looked, regardless.

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to search for things like '@'.  Completely understandable!

Comment: @DonRoby agreed whole-heartedly!

Comment: If you use quotes, then symbols are searched properly - e.g. search for `scala "@"` works, but search for `scala @` doesn't. I only just found this out by accident, though with hindsight it is mentioned in the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a *bind* operator. It allows you to assign an identifier to some complex pattern-matched value, so - for example - when pattern matching against case class, you can refer to both the fields of that case class as well as to the case class instance itself:

```
case class Record(intField: Int, stringField: String)

val something: Any = ...
something match {
   case entireInstance @ Record(intField, stringField) =>
       println(s"$entireInstance has fields $intField and $stringField")
}
```

Comment: Aha! That makes sense - so instead of just pattern matching the internals of the case object, I can bind an alias to the entire case object itself. Thank you!

Comment: It's also helpful when dealing with `Options` within case classes, e.g.,: `f @ Foo(Some(id), _, _)` when you just want to match for `Foos` with a defined ID.